# Find and Replace all different values with one value

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, is it possible to find a bunch different values and replace each one with a single value?

I want to replace the value inside the "" with a value of 10 in all of

delay milliseconds="###"/

There are over 1500+ of these. I hope there is a solution for this. Thanks.

```
      <key value="NUM3" direction="down"/>
      <delay milliseconds="141"/>
      <key value="NUM3" direction="up"/>
      <delay milliseconds="124"/>
      <key value="NUM4" direction="down"/>
      <delay milliseconds="175"/>
      <key value="NUM4" direction="up"/>
      <delay milliseconds="58"/>
      <key value="NUM9" direction="down"/>
      <delay milliseconds="137"/>
      <key value="NUM9" direction="up"/>
```

Comment: I have added a Regex based solution that can be done in 5 seconds. Please go through and try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly simple. All you need is to do a Regex replacement here with VS Code.

**Step 1 -** Run `Ctrl + Shift + F` to open bulk replacement / search tab in VS Code.

**Step 2 -** Select the Regex icon (`.*`) in the search input field.

**Step 3 -** Type the Regex `milliseconds="(.*?)"` in the tab to select every value you are expecting.

**Step 4 -** Replace text can be `milliseconds="10"` or whatever you want to keep for your value.

[image: Added screenshot for your reference]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! xD

Answer (score 0):

1. `"\d+"` in Find Widget (with regex option enabled).
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to select all matches.
3. Type `"10"`.  Done.